# Как узнать, есть ли элемент в массиве?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив: `['dog', 'cat', 'hamster', 'bird', 'fish']`, нужно вывести в консоль `true`, если массив содержит `dog` и `false` — если такой элемент отсутствует, но насколько я понимаю доступ к элементу в массиве проходит по номеру `array[..]`, каким образом можно проверить наличие того или иного элемента?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Используйте метод `indexOf`

```
var animals = ['dog', 'cat', 'hamster', 'bird', 'fish'];

alert( animals.indexOf( 'dog' ) != -1 );
```

Answer (score 105):

## Маленькая интродукция

---

Задача поиска элемента в массиве стоит перед всеми достаточно часто и хорошо бы расписать, как это можно сделать.

Ищут обычно в массиве элементы типа `Number`, `String` или `Object`. Естественно, самый быстрый способ поиска - по элементам типа `Number`, сравнение числа, даже очень большого, происходит очень быстро, гораздо проще проверить один элемент, чем лексиграфически сравнивать строки, а с объектами вообще другая история. Если мы ищем именно тот объект, который мы добавили в массив, то есть сравниваем ссылки - это так же быстро, как и сравнивать числа, а вот если же надо искать по свойствам объекта, то это может весьма и весьма затянуться. В особо сложных случаях, советую составлять какой-нибудь хэш объекта и строить отдельным массив-карту, в которой уже спокойно искать всё, что надо найти.

Разберем 6 способов сделать это на нативном JS разной новизны и 3 способа с их разбором на популярных фреймворках: [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), [underscore](http://underscorejs.ru) и [lodash](https://lodash.com/).

### Часть первая, нативная, в стиле аллегро

---

Для начала надо пройтись по родным возможностям языка и посмотреть, что можно сделать самим.

#### Поиск в лоб

Попробуем просто идти по элементам массива, пока мы не встретим то, что нам нужно. Как всегда самое простое решение является в среднем самым быстрым.

```
function contains(arr, elem) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === elem) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Работает везде. Сравнивает строго, с помощью `===`. Легко можно заменить на `==`, бывает полезно, когда элементы массива разных типов, но может замедлить поиск. Его можно и модифицировать, добавив возможность начинать поиск элемента с конца. Шикарно ищет цифры, строки. Немного расширив, можно добавить возможность поиска элемента по своему условию (это поможет нам искать по свойствам объекта или, например, первый элемент, который больше 100500):

```
function contains(arr, pred) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (typeof pred == 'function' && pred(arr[i], i, arr) || arr[i] === elem) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

#### Array.prototype.indexOf()

[`Array.prototype.indexOf(searchElement[, fromIndex = 0])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) - старый добрый метод, заставляющий всех мучиться со своей `-1` в случае, когда элемента нет.

```
function contains(arr, elem) {
   return arr.indexOf(elem) != -1;
}
```

Поддерживается он везде, кроме IE <= 7, но это уже давно забытая шутка. Данный метод выполняет поиск элемента строго от меньшего индекса к большему, применяя при сравнении `===`. Увы, по свойствам объекта мы так искать не сможем. `arr.indexOf(searchElement, fromIndex)` принимает два аргумента, первый `searchElement` - это элемент который ищем, а второй, `fromIndex`, индекс с которого начнем искать (отрицательный говорит интерпретатору начинать поиск с `arr.length + fromIndex` индекса). Аккуратней, если вы укажете `fromIndex` больше длины массива, метод нераздумывая вернёт `-1`.

```
function contains(arr, elem, from) {
   return arr.indexOf(elem, from) != -1;
}
```

#### Array.prototype.lastIndexOf()

[`Array.prototype.lastIndexOf(searchElement[, fromIndex = arr.length - 1])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) - справедливости ради надо рассказать и про него. Работает полностью аналогично `Array.prototype.indexOf()`, но только полностью наоборот (поиск идет в обратном порядке и `fromIndex` изначально отсчитывается с конца). Заменил конструкцию `ret != -1` на `!!~ret` ради забавы.

```
function contains(arr, elem, from) {
   return !!~arr.lastIndexOf(elem, from);
}
```

#### Array.prototype.find()

[`Array.prototype.find(callback[, thisArg])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) - модный стильный и молодежный ES6, со всеми вытекающими:

```
function contains(arr, elem) {
    return arr.find((i) => i === elem) != -1;
}
```

Возвращает элемент или `-1`, если ничего не найдено. Ищет с помощью `callback(elem, index, arr)`, то есть, если эта функция вернет `true`, то это именно тот самый, искомый элемент. Конечно, эту функцию можно задавать самому, поэтому метод универсален.

#### Array.prototype.findIndex()

[`Array.prototype.findIndex(callback[, thisArg])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) - полностью аналогичный предыдущему метод, за исключением того, что функция возвращает не элемент, а индекс. Забавы ради сделаю её с возможностью передать свою функцию:

```
function contains(arr, pred) {
    var f = typeof pred == 'function' ? pred : ( i => i === pred );
    return arr.findIndex(f) != -1;
}
```

#### Array.prototype.includes()

[`Array.prototype.includes(searchElement[, fromIndex])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) - а это уже ES7, с ещё пока оочень сырой поддержкой. Наконец-то у нас будет специальный метод, чтобы узнать, есть ли элемент в массиве! Поздравляю!

```
arr.includes(elem);
```

Это всё, что нужно, чтобы найти элемент. Аргументы у этой функции полностью аналогичны `Array.prototype.indexOf()`. А вот вернет он `true` в случае успеха и `false` в обратном. Естественно искать по свойствам объектов нельзя, для этого есть `Array.prototype.find()`. Должен быть самым быстрым, но... Возможно, что он и станет со временем самым быстрым.

### Часть вторая, со вниманием, но чужая и в стиле сонаты

---

Теперь, наконец, можно поговорить об этой же теме, но в контексте парочки фреймворков! Говорят, что всегда хорошо посмотреть сначала, как делают другие, перед тем, как начнешь делать это сам. Может это откроет нам глаза на что-нибудь интересное!

#### jQuery

[`jQuery.inArray(value, array [, fromIndex ])`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) - между прочим весьма быстрый метод, по тестам.

Использует внутри строгое равенство `===` и возвращает `-1`, если ничего не нашел, а если все таки нашёл, то вернет его индекс. Для удобства и одинаковости обернем её в функцию:

```
function contains(arr, elem) {
    return jQuery.inArray( elem, arr) != -1;
}
```

А теперь поговорим, как она работает. Вот, что она представляет из себя в версии `2.1.3`:

```
inArray: function( elem, arr, i ) {
    return arr == null ? -1 : indexOf.call( arr, elem, i );
}
```

Где `indexOf` это вот это:

```
// Use a stripped-down indexOf as it's faster than native
// http://jsperf.com/thor-indexof-vs-for/5
indexOf = function( list, elem ) {
    var i = 0,
        len = list.length;
    for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
        if ( list[i] === elem ) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Забавный комментарий говорит, что так быстрее, чем родной `Array.prototype.indexOf()` (могу предположить, что из-за отсутствия всех проверок) и предлагает посмотреть тесты производительности.

По сути - это самый первый способ из первой части.

#### Underscore

[`_.contains(list, value)`](http://underscorejs.ru/#contains) - вот такой метод предлагает нам популярная библиотека для работы с коллекциями. То же самое, что и `_.include(list, value)`.

Использует `===` для сравнения. Вернёт `true`, если в `list` содержится элемент, который мы ищем. Если list является массивом, будет вызван метод indexOf.

```
_.contains = _.include = function(obj, target) {
    if (obj == null) return false;
    if (nativeIndexOf && obj.indexOf === nativeIndexOf) return obj.indexOf(target) != -1;
    return any(obj, function(value) {
      return value === target;
    });
};
```

Где `nativeIndexOf` - штука, которая говорит, что `Array.prototype.indexOf()` существует, а `obj.indexOf === nativeIndexOf` говорит, что `list` - массив. Теперь понятно, почему этот метод медленнее, чем `jQuery.inArray()`, просто обертка над `Array.prototype.indexOf()`. Ничего интересного.

#### Lodash

[`_.includes(collection, target, [fromIndex=0])`](https://lodash.com/docs#includes) - вот последняя надежда на новые мысли, от второй знаменитейшей библиотеки для работы с коллекциями. То же самое, что `_.contains()` и `_.include()`.

Возвращает `true`, если содержит и `false` если нет. `fromIndex` индекс элемента, с которого начинаем поиск.

```
function includes(collection, target, fromIndex, guard) {
    var length = collection ? getLength(collection) : 0;
    if (!isLength(length)) {
        collection = values(collection);
        length = collection.length;
    }
    if (typeof fromIndex != 'number' || (guard && isIterateeCall(target, fromIndex, guard))) {
        fromIndex = 0;
    } else {
        fromIndex = fromIndex < 0 ? nativeMax(length + fromIndex, 0) : (fromIndex || 0);
    }
    return (typeof collection == 'string' || !isArray(collection) && isString(collection))
        ? (fromIndex <= length && collection.indexOf(target, fromIndex) > -1)
        : (!!length && getIndexOf(collection, target, fromIndex) > -1);
}
```

`guard` - служебный аргумент. Сначала находится длина коллекции, выбирается `fromIndex`, а потом... нет, не `Array.prototype.indexOf()`! Для поиска в строке используется `String.prototype.indexOf()`, а мы идем дальше в `_.getIndexOf()` и в результате попадём в ло-дашскую имплементацию `indexOf()`:

```
function indexOf(array, value, fromIndex) {
    var length = array ? array.length : 0;
    if (!length) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (typeof fromIndex == 'number') {
        fromIndex = fromIndex < 0 ? nativeMax(length + fromIndex, 0) : fromIndex;
    } else if (fromIndex) {
        var index = binaryIndex(array, value);
        if (index < length &&
            (value === value ? (value === array[index]) : (array[index] !== array[index]))) {
            return index;
    }
    return -1;
  }
  return baseIndexOf(array, value, fromIndex || 0);
}
```

Она интересна тем, что `fromIndex` может принимать значения как `Number`, так и `Boolean` и если это всё таки значение булевого типа и оно равно `true`, то функция будет использовать бинарный поиск по массиву! Прикольно. Иначе же выполнится `indexOf()` попроще:

```
function baseIndexOf(array, value, fromIndex) {
    if (value !== value) {
        return indexOfNaN(array, fromIndex);
    }
    var index = fromIndex - 1,
        length = array.length;
    while (++index < length) {
        if (array[index] === value) {
            return index;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Интересный ход для случая, когда мы ищем `NaN` (напомню, что из-за досадной ошибки он не равен сам себе). Выполнится `indexOfNaN()`, и действительно ни один из всех способов описанных ранее не смог бы найти `NaN`, кроме тех, естественно, где мы могли сами указать функцию для отбора элементов.

Можно предложить просто обернуть `_.indexOf()` для поиска элемента:

```
function contains(arr, elem, fromIndex) {
    return _.indexOf(arr, elem, fromIndex) != -1;
}
```

Где `fromIndex` будет либо индексом откуда начинаем искать, либо `true`, если мы знаем, что `arr` отсортирован.

### Заключение, хотя и в стиле интермеццо

---

И да, все эти варианты имеют смысл, только если момент с поиском данных част в вашем алгоритме или поиск происходит на очень больших данных. Вот приведу ниже несколько тестов на поиск элементов типа `Number` и `String` в массивах длинной 1000000 (миллион) элементов для трех случаев, когда элемент находится вначале массива, в середине (можно считать за среднюю по палете ситуацию) и в конце (можно считать за время поиска отсутствующего элемента, кроме метода с `Array.prototype.lastIndexOf()`).

1. [`Number`, 1000000 элементов, искомый элемент в начале](http://jsperf.com/testfindeleminarray/8);
2. [`Number`, 1000000 элементов, искомый элемент в середине](http://jsperf.com/testfindeleminarray/9);
3. [`Number`, 1000000 элементов, искомый элемент в конце](http://jsperf.com/testfindeleminarray/10);
4. [`String`, 1000000 элементов, искомый элемент в начале](http://jsperf.com/testfindeleminarray/13);
5. [`String`, 1000000 элементов, искомый элемент в середине](http://jsperf.com/testfindeleminarray/12);
6. [`String`, 1000000 элементов, искомый элемент в конце](http://jsperf.com/testfindeleminarray/11).

Результаты тестов могут сильно зависеть от версии браузера, да и от самих браузеров, как этого избежать не знаю, но рекомендую протестить на нескольких.

Видно, что в среднем везде выигрывает первый способ из первой части (написанный собственноручно), а второе место обычно делят lоdash и `Array.prototype.includes()`.

Да, прошу заметить, что если взбредёт в голову искать `NaN`, то это может не получиться почти во всех методах, так как `NaN !== NaN`.

Comment: Ох, вылил душу)

Comment: Ничего себе, я плюсанул даже не читая...

Comment: @stckvrw, а зря, мог я и ошибиться) Еще чуть позже тесты добавлю.

Comment: За усилия плюсанул, не за правильность)

Comment: Ого, фундаментальный труд!

Comment: У вас в аллегро, второй сниппет, `function contains(arr, pred)`, не определён `elem` по идее. (И я бы выяснял, функция у нас там или нет, один раз до обхода списка, и в зависимости от результата выполнял разные циклы.)

Answer (score 3):

```js
animals.some(item => item === "dog");    // true
```

Он будет искать вхождение и если найдет сразу вернет `true` и прекратит двежение, если нечего не найдет отдаст `false`

Также можно использовать `includes()` -- тоже возвращает булевное значение, он чуствителен к регистру пример:

```js
animals.includes("dog");    // true
animals.includes("Dog");    // false
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще такой вариант встречал:

```
if(new RegExp(animals.join("|")).test("dog")) {
```

Comment: /cat|dog|hamster/.test('doggy') - напишет `true`

Comment: Точно, значит не годится, не проверял на обратность

Comment: Я долго думал над тем, как можно обыграть регулярки, но слишком много надо учитывать. В итоге результат вообще не радовал, не знаю может и можно как-то.